# How to pass javascript variable to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I am using [selectable jquery](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid) in my jsp page. On submitting the form, the string should pass as parameter to servlet.

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I want `var result` as value in `<input type="hidden" id="select-result" value=""/>`

Form -

```
<form action="XYZServlet" method="get">
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
 <input type="hidden" id="select-result" value="">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: could you please post your form code.

Comment: added my form code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the ***index***, right?

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
                document.getElementById("my").value = index;
            });      
        }
    });
});
```

You can view the ***Value as index(selected item)*** - `<input type="text" id="my" value=""/>`

I hope this will work :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                result.append(" #" + (index + 1));
            });
        $("#select-result").val(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i changed input type as text & found out value = [object Object]

Comment: Try casting the value `[object Object]` into String